# maven release:prepare fails; seems to be confused about svn's UUID

Tags: svn, maven-2, release, visualsvn-server

When I try to use the Maven release plugin, it fails on `mvn release:prepare` with the following error:

```
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Unable to tag SCM
Provider message:
The svn tag command failed.
Command output:
svn: Repository UUID '3da89ab5-aa79-4544-a1de-ca02bd87a2ce' doesn't match expect
ed UUID '221b71b0-5d3c-7840-b153-25850b4df36e'
```

I am certain the repository UUID is 221b71b0-5d3c-7840-b153-25850b4df36e, and have tested checkins and check out.

I have deleted all local source code and checked it out again, still the same error.

I have confirmed that in the svn entries file, it references the correct UUID 221b71b0-5d3c-7840-b153-25850b4df36e.

I have run `svnlook uuid e:\repositories\myrepo` and it returns 221b71b0-5d3c-7840-b153-25850b4df36e.

But somehow, Maven thinks the UUID is different when it tries to tag.

I am able to create my own tags with the svn client. My svn server is local on my machine it is VisualSVN running under Vista. I am also able to check files in and out with Eclipse.

I am at my wits end on this! The only thing I can think of is that the local machine name is different from the repository URL. I.e., I am using DynDNS to route traffic to repo.mydomain.com, and it's all set up in my router to route the traffic to the appropriate service. In other words, the OS thinks my machine name is A_NAME, but I am accessing svn via the URL repo.mydomain.com. Is it possible that maven getting confused because of this?

Between Maven and VisualSVN I have no idea what to do. Please help!

Final note: when I run Maven with the -e param, I get this stack trace:

```
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.BuildFailureException: Unable to tag SCM
Provider message:
The svn tag command failed.
Command output:
svn: Repository UUID '3da89ab5-aa79-4544-a1de-ca02bd87a2ce' doesn't match expect
ed UUID '221b71b0-5d3c-7840-b153-25850b4df36e'

        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(Defa
ultLifecycleExecutor.java:715)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandalone
Goal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(Defau
ltLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHan
dleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegmen
ts(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:284)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLi
fecycleExecutor.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:6
0)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)

        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Unable to tag SCM
Provider message:
The svn tag command failed.
Command output:
svn: Repository UUID '3da89ab5-aa79-4544-a1de-ca02bd87a2ce' doesn't match expect
ed UUID '221b71b0-5d3c-7840-b153-25850b4df36e'

        at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.execute(PrepareRe
leaseMojo.java:169)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPlugi
nManager.java:490)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(Defa
ultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
        ... 17 more
```

Answer (score 1):

I feel like a numnut, but it tunrs out that when I was switching around my svn repositories, I neglected to update the pom.xml. It all makes sense now. But I really wish Maven would list the repositories it was using in the output. It would have saved me a full day of hair pulling!

Answer (score 0):

Hey so what was the change you had to make to your POM?  Our team has encountered the same issue with the maven-release-plugin.  I've tried a clean checkout and verified that the hostname used for the scm config in the POM and the hostname used to checkout the working folder is the same.  Is there something else you discovered that's needed to fix the POM?

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem. It got resolved by:

1. clean checkout from SVN.
2. mark new snapshot av version of the
   artifact.
3. make sure latest version of plugin is used.

mvn release:help will display version number.

latest as of today:
    org.apache.maven.plugins
    maven-release-plugin
    2.2.2